# What does this command means "-c"?

Tags: java, android, su

I was looking at some codes, and found this code

```
{ "su", "-c", "reboot" }
```

I know that this will make your phone to reboot, because it ask for su first then reboot, but I don't know what that -c means.

Its like an enter button on the keyboard? also could I add as much ones as I want? something like

```
{ "su", "-c", "code", "-c", "code", "-c", "code" }
```

Thanks

Comment: RTFD: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-c` is a flag that tells the `su` command to execute the command following `-c`. So in this case, it is simply, as root, telling the system to reboot.

[Some documentation on the `su` command.](http://www.linfo.org/su.html)

Answer (score 0):

`su reboot` already means "give me a session under the credentials of a user named `reboot`".
So there has to be a way to indicate that `reboot` is not the name of a user to become, but the name of a command to run (as superuser).

(Does your system not have a man page for `su`?)